# Geometric Interpretation of $Re(\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2 })=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to find the loci of points $z$ in the complex plane that satisfy 
$$Re\left(\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2 }\right)=0$$

where $z_1$ and $z_2$ are fixed points.

I understand that this is a line which coincides with the imaginary axis, but I couldn't prove it algebraically.

Comment: Making the denominator real by multiplying with the conjugate is a good way to start: $\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2} = \frac{(z-z_1)(z^*-z_2^*)}{|z-z_2|^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=a+ib$, $z_j=a_j+ib_j$, where all $a$ and $b$ are reals.

Then the equation $$\Re\left(\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right)=0$$is equivalent to
$$\Re\left(\frac{(z-z_1)(\bar z-\bar z_2)}{|z-z_2|^2}\right)=0,$$
$$\Re\left( (z-z_1)(\bar z-\bar z_2) \right)=0,$$
which gives the equation
$$(a-a_1)(a-a_2)+(b-b_1)(b-b_2)=0.$$
This is the equation of a circle:

$$\left(a-\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}\right)^2+\left(b-\frac{b_1+b_2}{2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{a_1-a_2}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b_1-b_2}{2}\right)^2.$$
Or, in terms of $z$,
$$\left|z-\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}\right|^2 = \left| \frac{z_1-z_2}{2}\right|^2.$$

Comment: it's the circle centered at the midpoint of the segment between $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ with radius equal to $1/2$ the distance between $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$, right? (So, the points $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ would lie on the circle)

Comment: @JessyCat exactly